# MongoDB MapReduce same key several times?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

Firs of all: a 'Yes' or 'No' - with link to docs will suffice as answer.

In mongo dbs mapreduce, can the reduce function be called several times for the same key or am I guaranteed that the reduce function is called once per key?

Let's say I have the following input to the map function:

```
{ id: 1, day: 1, category: 1, value: 5 }, 
{ id: 2, day: 1, category: 2, value: 5 }, 
{ id: 3, day: 2, category: 2, value: 7 },
{ id: 4, day: 2, category: 2, value: 7 }
```

The following key:

```
{ 'day': this.day, 'category': this.category }
```

And emit the following values for each key:

```
{ 'value': this.value }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the reduce can be called multiple times for the same key, unless there is only one result in which case the reduce is not called at all since there is nothing to reduce: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/troubleshoot-reduce-function/#ensure-reduce-function-idempotence

Answer (score 1):

Or more precisely that yes or no, a working example of [mapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/):

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function() {
        emit(
            { "day": this.day, "category": this.category },
            this.value
        );
    },
    function(key, value) {
        var reduced = 0;
        values.forEach(function(value) {
            reduced += value;
        });
        return reduced;
    },
    {
        "out": { "inline": 1 }
    }
)
```

But of course in the data you provide as the "key" will be different in every case, the "reduce" function is not actually called. What happens here is that the values from the "mapper" are simply sent through to the output without being touched.

Only when there are actually "multiple" values for the same key is the "reduce" function actually called. This is the whole point of mapReduce.

Comment: You are of course right. I added one more value to the list to clarify the intent of the question. Thank you.